# Implementing Trigonometric Inverse Functions in c#

Tags: c#, trigonometry, inverse

I'm trying to implement inverse trigonometric functions in a C# application.  Obviously I'm not talking about simple inverse sin, cos and tan seeing as those are all provided by the Math class.  What I'm looking for is the inverses for sec, cosec and cotan:

```
Func<double,double> secant = (d => (1 / Math.Cos(d)));
Func<double,double> cosecant = (d => (1 / Math.Sin(d)));
Func<double,double> cotangent = (d => (Math.Cos(d) / Math.Sin(d)));
```

Now my problem is that I want to implement the inverses of each of these but I can't seem to find a simple definition of the appropriate inverses - arcsec, arccsc and arccot - which I can turn into C# code.

So my question is can you either (a) point me in the direction of a good resource or (b) show me some example code for this?

Comment: Have you checked MathWorld for the formulae for the inverses you want ?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might not need to do any serious math to do that hence you don't need a 'definition'; you only need to prepare a lookup table.

Comment: I spent quite a while on Wikipedia, the formulas Chris just posted are not obvious on <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions> if they are there at all

Comment: I just worked them backwards from your formulae for sec, csc, and cot.

Comment: I kinda feel dumb for failing to apply basic algebra :-(

Comment: +1 for balancing the downvotes to a good question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Surely you jest:

```
asec(x) = acos(1 / x)
acsc(x) = asin(1 / x)
acot(x) = atan(1 / x)
```

:-P

Comment: Yeah but it wasn't exactly obvious among the mountains of other equations - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms

Comment: remember also to add code to avoid the well-known divide by zero problem

Answer (score 0):

For inverse cotangent, using atan(1 / x) will not always work. For example, I needed to do a fairly complicated equation:

y = 0.25 * arccot((2.5x / 100000) - 2.1) + 0.26

When implementing the atan(1 / x) solution, it results in a break when (2.5x / 100000) - 2.1 is zero, and all the values to the left of that point are below the correct values by pi / 4.

Instead, using an implementation as such provides the exact answers for all points needed:

y = 0.25 * ((pi / 2) - atan((2.5x / 100000) -2.1) + 0.26

I would suggest going to desmos.com/calculator or some other graphing utility and graphing the actual arccot function, then comparing various implementations to make sure you are getting what you want for all values.